# SSRS Filter Parameter value from Query String

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, query-string

I have SSRS Report which has Filter Parameters which appear as dropdown list on my Page. I want to select these parameters from querystring. 
How to do this?

Comment: do you mean you have to type them manually? You want to be able to select from a set of respective values?

Comment: do you want to select your parameter from a drop down list, and all those items in the drop down will be fetched by a query?